# Change the title of a Google form based on a user response form.getResponses()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to Google Apps Script. I am trying to change the title of a form based on a user response. I am working on a basic inventory check in check out system. I have got the check in/check out function to work from using the code below.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var title = form.getTitle()
if(title == 'Checked Out'){
  form.setTitle('Checked in')}
  else{form.setTitle('Checked Out');}}`
```

One of the questions on my form is **what is your name?** so ideally I would like to add **checked out by Mr.X**. The only way I have seen how to pull out user responses is by running a for loop and pulling out all the responses and calling the placement from the resulting array. Does anyone have a better way to pull out user responses? or a good resource where I can find out the answers to questions like this myself?